# Looping schema in Python

Tags: python

I do not quite understand how Python loops through a list and a file.

Lets say I have the file which looks like this:

`textfile`:

```
Stations
--------
stn       Name                                 Parameter        Data source                              Longitude/Latitude       Coordinates [km] Elevation [m]
ARA       Arolla                               rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0
BOQ       Bouquetins                           rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0
BRE       Bréona                               rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0
CDR       Col de Riedmatten                    rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0       
CTZ       Crettaz                              rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0                                           
HOL       Hohlicht                             rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0        
TRI       Trift                                rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0        
TAP       Täschalp                             rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0        
VOU       Vouasson                             rre250c0         XX                                                 XXX             XXX             0
```

And thats my code:

```
statList = ["ARA", "BOQ", "BRE", "CDR", "CTZ",
            "FEP", "HOL", "TRI", "TAP", "VOU"]

legend34413 = open("textfile.txt", "r")

for k in statList:
    for i in legend34413:
        print k #always prints "ARA"
        #do more stuff
```

However, it seems that my first for loop does not go through the whole `statList`. It only prints `ARA` for each line in the file, but then not the next, which would be `BOQ`.
Why is that?!

Answer (score 4):

Once the loop has executed once, and printed `ARA` for every line in the file, it will have reached the end of the file and exhausted the iterator. If you want it to go back and start again from the beginning, you will need to rewind it:

```
for k in statList:
    for i in legend34413:
        print k
    legend34413.seek(0)
```

Now your code will print `ARA` once for every line in the file. Then it will print `BOQ` once for every line in the file, then it will print `BRE` once for every line, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, the first step in Python's iteration protocol is to create an **iterator object** for an *iterable* that you wish to iterate over. So in a for loop like `for item in l:`, where `l` is a list, Python first creates an **iterator object** for `l`and then iterates over *that* object:

```
iterator_object = iter(l)
iterator_object.__next__()
iterator_object.__next__()
...
```

It also first creates an iterator object when it iterates over a file object. But, and this is the key point, a file object **is its own iterator** (f = iter(f)). So, using the same iteration protocol,

```
f = iterator_object = iter(f)
f.__next__()
f.__next__()
...
```

And you can see that `l` can be iterated over any number of times whereas `f` is exhausted after its first pass.

So when your code reaches the inner for loop the second time, the iterator object that Python internally gets from `legend34413`, **which is `legend34413`**, is exhausted. So the print statement is never reached for subsequent `statList` elements.